# Predict follow up time using parametric model in r

Tags: r, prediction, survival-analysis

I am trying to predict follow-up time using several survival models, both parametric and semi-parametric. I achieve it for semi parametric models using `predict.coxph` function in R using `type = "expected"` as indicated in help. However, for parametric models, this option doesn't exist for the `predict.survreg` function. Is there any other option? Maybe using `rms` package?